# How to see iphone app how it works without having iphone?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I want to make an app in android like one of `iphone` app. I mean android version for an `iphone` app. So i need to see this iphone app working on `iphone`. I have this iphone app codes but it has provision profile problem. There is no free provision creation right? i just need to see how it is work in similator. But i cant see. I dont have iphone to download this app. can i use `iphone similator` to download iphone app from store to see how it works? How to know how it works?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to explain? Check this for how to ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Are you running it on XCode, if so you can directly run it on simulator, where you can check most of it;s functionality?

Comment: @rptwsthi Can i debug an iphone app in xcode without having provision profile? I mean i ll use xcode to debug app and see it in similator.. is tihs free? to develop an iphone app an debug in similator

Comment: Yes.. Completely free.

Comment: @rptwsthi but it requires provision profile and when i try to get provision profile i m getting not free servise from apple website... How to debug without provision profile

Comment: @rptwsthi Also Thanks for repliying to me

Answer (score 1):

Taking your question one by one:

1. There is no free provision creation right?

   - *Lucky for you there is, [Check it here](https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/).*
2. I just need to see how it is work in simulator. But I cant see.

   - *Select a Simulator before running application:*
     [image]

If there is problem with that, manage the scheme.

3. I don't have iphone to download this app. Can I use iphone simulator to download iphone app from store to see how it works?

   - *No, you cant download an app from app-store to simulator.*

Comment: "No, you cant download an app from app-store to simulator." Ohhh no :( Thanks for explanation